# extract function fails for different length record

Tags: r, extract, tidyr

In below code `extract` is ok for first row , but failed for second row. Anyone can help on this?

And, I have to define c(1:6) `LETTERS[c(1:6)]` for the columns names , is there way like `LETTERS[c(1:variable)]` for this ? Thanks!

```
library(tidyverse)
test_data <- data.frame(category=c("az_b1_wj_1_k_z","f_2_wj"))
test_data %>% extract(category,LETTERS[c(1:6)],"(.+)_(.+)_(.+)_(.+)_(.+)_(.+)")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `extract` use `separate` and the `extra = "merge"` argument:

```
library(tidyr)
test_data %>%
  separate(category, into = LETTERS[1:6], extra = "merge")
   A  B  C    D    E    F
1 az b1 wj    1    k    z
2  f  2 wj <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

`extra` controls what happens when there are too many pieces, while `"merge"` automatically splits at maximum `length(into)` times

If you don't know in advance how many columns you want to separate into, you can first define a vector with the `max`imum number of columns by using `str_count` to count the number of underscores in your stringr (plus 1):

```
library(stringr)
col <- max(str_count(test_data$category, "_") +1)
```

and then input that vector into the `into` argument:

```
test_data %>%
  separate(category, into = LETTERS[seq_len(col)], extra = "merge")
```

If you prefer to do everything within a single piece of code in `tidyverse`:

```
test_data %>%
  mutate(col = max(str_count(category, "_") +1)) %>%
  separate(category, into = LETTERS[seq_len(col[1])], extra = "merge") %>%
  select(-col)
```